# Kernel panic on a 2012 MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

[image]

This is MacBook Air 2012 A1706
Now it doesn't even power on.  It just makes 3 short tones.

Where could be a problem?

Comment: Try to do a safe boot, restart your Mac and hold down the Shift key until you see the gray Apple logo. Did you install any weird software?

Comment: It's not booting up anymore, just makes 3 short sounds

Comment: It's most likely your memory.  Post your exact model MacBook so we can give you better instructions to possibly fix.

Comment: This is MacBook Air 2012 8GB

Comment: @mu3 please post the model number (printed on the bottom). It looks something like this: A1706

Comment: The model is A1466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three short tones with a 5 second interval between sets is indicative of a RAM failure

From Apple's support document:  [About Mac startup tones](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768)

> Three successive tones, then a five-second pause (repeating): RAM
>   doesn't pass a data integrity check.

The MacBook Air doesn't have any user serviceable memory, so it's a logic board issue.  Since you cannot boot, there's really no other option but to take it in for service.

It's likely that Apple will want to replace the logic board for a large sum of money.  I suggest looking at a reputable 3rd party repair shop.  I have used [Rossmann Repair Group](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/) in the past with great success (not affiliated, just a client)

He even has a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/lwg2YQ62W8A) with your exact problem and how he fixes it; it's technical, but full of good info.  Caution:  he's from NYC so his language is typically colorful.